# how create simple side menu with jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, slidetoggle

i have menu in side location and that code is :

```
<ul>
<li>
    <span class="arz">
        first menu
    </span>
    <ul  id="arz">
        <li>
            first submenu
        </li>
        <li>
            second submenu
        </li>
        <li>
            third submenu
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="words">
    two menu
    <ul id="words">
        <li>
            first submenu
        </li>
        <li>
            second submenu
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submenu").click(function(){
        $(this).children(this).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

but i want by clicking on *first menu* `ul` element with `id="arz" using`slideToggle`,

this code do it but when i click on every submenu item corresponding ul use`slideToggle`.
by thanks
aya

Comment: The html you've shown doesn't use the ".reading" or ".submenu" classes, nor does it have any paragraph elements, so your two jQuery selectors will not find any elements to assign click handlers to. Have you just copied the jQuery from somewhere else, or is there more relevant html you haven't shown, or...? (Aside from that, you don't need two document.ready functions. Create both click handlers inside a single document.ready.)

Comment: oh , sorry i insert extra code thanks for reminder

Comment: Um...the class mentioned in your jQuery code ("submenu") is _still_ not mentioned in your html. Also, is there some reason why only the first top-level menu has a span in it? It would be easier to answer your question if your html had a uniform structure and used class name(s) that matched your jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery code you reference a class that is not present in your html. That's why it isn't working. Here is something slightly modified that works as you can see in this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7c52w/1/)

**HTML**

```
<style>
    ul.submenu{display:none;background:#ccc;}
</style>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="arz">
        <span>first menu</span>
        <ul id="arz" class="submenu">
            <li>
                first submenu
            </li>
            <li>
                first submenu
            </li>
            <li>
                first submenu
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="words">
        <span>second menu</span>
        <ul id="words" class="submenu">
            <li>
                second submenu
            </li>
            <li>
                second submenu
            </li>
            <li>
                second submenu
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.menu li').click(function(){
        $(this).find('ul.submenu').slideToggle('slow')
    })
})
```

Comment: oh my God , thanks Pastor Bones . this is very good help . i didn't his particular of this site ??? and your code is very good. thanks

Comment: hi , this code is good , but when i clicking on `submenus` menu Item toggling while i just want `submenus` toggle when clicking on menus Item.

Comment: i find modified  `$('ul.menu li span').click(function(){$(this).parent(this).find('ul.submenu').slideToggle('slow')` is better for my goal.